# Merge a specific commit on top of master

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo, on git log -3 --online it looks like this,

```
f5d394d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Bug Fix
7d465b6 Show version and other important details
67a69a6 Bug fix in Timeout
```

The top commit is wrongly pushed and I want to go to commit 7d465b6, make required changes and push back on top of master.

I have tried,

```
git checkout 7d465b6
//MAde Chnages
```

But on git branch it is showing,

```
* (HEAD detached from 7d465b6)
master
```

And I cannot merge..

How can I achieve this? I want to make changes in commit 2 and push back to origin/master

Comment: Working alone on that repo? Or is `master` shared?

Comment: Shared. It is a remote repo

Comment: Your proposed course of action doesn't suit well with a shared branch. You'll mess up your coworker's branch history (if the operation is even permitted on the remote end). You should consider adding a new commit on top rather than modifying what's already been pushed. `git revert <bad commit>` is also a tool at your disposal, since it avoids rewriting history. Check it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj9_oGczb7tAhUIcBQKHVZYBcUQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgit-scm.com%2Fdocs%2Fgit-revert&usg=AOvVaw3cQVMMEv_MKp70KbERqwr9).

Answer (score 2):

As [RomainValeri noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200541/merge-a-specific-commit-on-top-of-master#comment115268168_65200541), your end goal is perhaps not the best end goal: if you achieve it, you may cause problems for other users of this same repository.  The immediate problem you're experiencing, though, is simple enough.  This:

> ```
> * (HEAD detached from 7d465b6)
> ```

indicates that you are in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  You might wonder what this phrase means.  It has a very specific definition, but for your purposes, it means you aren't using `master`, which explains why you are not getting what you want.

Before we get started in how to achieve what you're trying to achieve, and how to achieve what you maybe should do instead, let's look at this particular `git log` output though:

> ```
> f5d394d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Bug Fix
> 7d465b6 Show version and other important details
> 67a69a6 Bug fix in Timeout
> ```

Git has encoded a fair amount of information here.  One important part that it *hasn't* encoded, though, is the structure of the *commit graph*.  (To see that, you have to add `--graph` to your `git log` command.)  To talk about this properly, we have to talk about what a commit is and does for you, in Git, and get into how Git really works.

#### Git is about commits

Git consists primarily of two databases.  One of these—usually the biggest one—is a database of all of Git's *commit objects* and other internal objects.  This database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), in which the keys, by which Git finds the commit objects, are hash IDs.  Importantly to Git, every object in the database is read-only.  This means no part of any object, including a commit object, can ever be changed.

Those numbers at the left of each line, such as `f5d394d`, are *commit hash IDs*.  (Technically, they're also abbreviated.  The full hash ID is much longer.  This is just the first seven [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) digits.)  So these numbers are how Git finds the commits: it just looks them up in its big database of all Git objects, to get the commit objects.

Each commit consists of two parts:

- One part holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  The files "inside" a commit are actually stored as separate objects in the Git object database, compressed and de-duplicated.  This way, it doesn't matter if this commit re-uses all but one file from the previous commit.  Since the files are stored *as* objects, those re-used files just re-use the existing objects.  Of course, since no object can ever be changed, none of these committed files can ever be changed either (which makes sharing them OK).
- The other part of a commit consists of information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and why (their log message), for instance.  Git calls this the commit's *metadata* (the data being the source snapshot).  In the metadata, Git stores one list for its own use: every commit has a list of the raw commit hash IDs of some set of *previous* commits.

Most commits store exactly one previous-commit hash ID.  These are your ordinary everyday commits.  The one previous-commit hash ID they store forms a simple backwards link, in a simple backwards-looking chain of commits.  We can draw this!  We could use real hash IDs, but they're big and ugly and random-looking.  If we use a single uppercase letter for each commit, we'll run out after just a few commits (26 with the English alphabet, more or less with other alphabets) but we can keep better track of our drawing, so let's do that:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for `f5d394d`: the *last* commit in the chain.  Git drew this at the top of its listing, while I've drawn it towards the right, to indicate that it's the last one.

Commit `H` has inside it a full snapshot of every file (as its data), and your name and email address and your message "Bug fix" and so on as its metadata.  In that metadata, Git has stored `7d465b6`: the actual hash ID of the commit we'll just call `G`.

Commit `G` has inside it a full snapshot of every file (as of its form earlier), and your name and email address and your message "Show version and other important details", and the hash ID (`67a69a6`) of earlier commit `F`.

Commit `F` has inside it ... well, you should get the idea by now.  See how, if we know the hash ID of commit `H`, we can have Git extract commit `H`, and then use that to find commit `G`?  Then Git can go back to commit `F`, and from `F`, Git can go further back.  Git can, in other words, find the *entire history of this chain of commits* by walking, one commit at a time, from each commit to its earlier or *parent* commit.

#### Branch names, and other names, let Git *find* commits

That first `git log` line reads:

> ```
> f5d394d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) ...
> ```

The stuff in the parentheses—including the name `master`—are *ways Git can find this commit*.  The *branch name* `master` holds hash ID `f5d394d` (the full one, not the abbreviated one we showed).  The *remote-tracking name* `origin/master` holds the same hash ID.  The two names with `HEAD` in them are kind of special, and we'll ignore both for just a moment here.

In my shortened way of drawing commits, I would do this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, I've replaced the arrows from each commit back to its parent with a direct connecting line.  This is partly from laziness and partly because I don't have good arrow characters when I want to draw the lines like this:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G
```

for instance.

#### The special name `HEAD`

In all cases, `H` still points backwards to `G`, but when I do the above, I can draw something pointing to `G`, like this:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
```

In the last drawing, the special name `HEAD` is no longer attached to the name `master`.  In *Git's* drawing:

> ```
> f5d394d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) ...
> ```

the special name `HEAD` is *pointing to* the name `master`, which in some ways is better.  But *attaching* the special name *to* master, as in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

helps to explain why the other mode is called a *detached HEAD*.  The special name `HEAD` is either *attached to* a branch name, or *detached*.

When `HEAD` is attached to a branch name, Git says that you are "on" that branch:

> ```
> $ git status
> On branch master
> ```

for instance.

When `HEAD` is *detached*, `git status` won't say that you're "on" a branch, and your `git branch` output will say things like `HEAD detached from ...`.

The special name `HEAD` exists *at all times*, though, and *always* tells Git what your *current commit* is.  If it's attached to a branch name, that current commit's hash ID is stored in the branch name, and you're "on" that branch.  So if `master` points to `H`, and `HEAD` is attached to `master`, then `HEAD` finds commit `H` and you're on branch `master`.

When you ran:

> ```
> git checkout 7d465b6
> ```

you told your Git to *detach* `HEAD` from the name `master`.  Now `HEAD` just holds the raw hash ID `7d465b6` (the full one, though).  This is the commit I'm calling `G` and this means you're in this situation:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
```

#### Most of what we do in Git involves making *new* commits

Whenever we make a *new* commit, we're telling Git to:

1. Make a new snapshot: this will be the data for the new commit.
2. Collect up new metadata, for the new commit: your name and email address (from the `git config` settings `user.name` and `user.email`), a log message, and the *current commit's hash ID* as found by reading `HEAD`.
3. Write all of these together as a new commit, which acquires a new and unique hash ID.  (To guarantee uniqueness, Git adds the *current* date-and-time, so that even if we've somehow re-used all the files, and re-used the user name and so on, the new commit is still different from the previous one.)
4. There is a step 4, but let's draw the result of the first three steps.

Suppose we are in your detached-HEAD state:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
```

We get Git to write out a new commit, with an unpredictable hash ID.  The hash ID includes the exact second at which you make the commit, which we can't predict, so we don't know what the hash ID will be.  But we'll just call it commit `I` since that's the next letter after `H`:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I
```

Note how `I` points back to commit `G`.  That's because commit `G` was the `HEAD` commit when we made it.

What about the various names?  Well, let's finish with step 4 now:

4. Write the new commit's hash ID to the branch name that `HEAD` indicates.

But `HEAD` is detached!  We can't write the hash ID to *any* branch name.  What Git does in this case is fall back to writing the new hash ID into `HEAD`:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- HEAD
```

So our *new* commit is only *find*-able using the special name `HEAD`.

If we run:

```
git checkout master
```

to re-attach our `HEAD` to `master`, we get:

```
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   ???
```

Who holds the hash ID for commit `I`?  The answer is: *nobody*.  You can't *find* the hash ID any more.  **The commit still exists but you can't find it.**

#### The wrong way: force-push

Now, there *are* some of ways to find hash IDs of lost commits, so as to recover from this kind of mistake.  These mostly involve using what Git calls its *reflogs*.  Suppose we use one of those to find commit `I`.  Then, we tell Git to force the *name* `master` to identify commit `I`.  (There are multiple ways to do this, though we won't look at any of them here.)  What we'll get is this:

```
          H   ???
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

What happened to commit `H`?  As before, *nothing:* it's still there, it's just harder to find.  In our case it's actually still easy to find for now, because the *remote-tracking name* `origin/master` finds it:

```
          H   <-- origin/master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The *reason* our `origin/master` finds commit `H` is that, the last time we had our Git talk to the Git over on GitHub, the repository over there had *its* `master` pointing to its copy of commit `H`.

(Commits, when pushed to other Git repositories, *keep* their unique hash IDs.  All Gits everywhere compute the *same* hash ID for the same internal Git object, always.  This is how the "distributed" part of Git works.  These letters, standing in for Git hash IDs, are shared across all clones.  The *branch names* aren't!)

If we want to send this commit to *another* Git, such as the one over on GitHub, and have the GitHub Git repository use *its* `master` to identify commit `I`, we'll make that *other* Git repository lose track of *its* copy of commit `H`.

The result in our Git will be this:

```
          H   ???
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

where nobody can find `H` any more—except, that is, anyone *else* who cloned the GitHub repository, who has *their own* `master` pointing to *their* copy of commit `H`.

So, this method can work.  It's just that if we do it, we're making problems for everyone else who has a clone of the GitHub repository.  They will now have to take steps to update *their* repositories, to drop commit `H` (`f5d394d`, really).  Hence, while we *could* force the name `master` to point to commit `I`, and thus "lose" commit `H`, and then use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` to send our update to `master` to the Git repository over on GitHub, we *shouldn't* do that.

#### What we should do instead of force-push

Git is in general built to *add* commits.  Note that in our attempt to *remove* commit `H`, we're going against this general philosophy.  What if we go *with* it instead?  Suppose that instead of *removing* commit `H`, which has an error in it, we just add a commit `J` that *undoes* what commit `H` did?

We can do this with:

```
git checkout master
git revert master
```

The first command gets us back "on" `master`, so that commit `H` is our current commit:

```
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   ???
```

We can't find `I` easily any more, so we'll just stop drawing it entirely:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now we run the `git revert` command.  Revert needs to get the hash ID of the commit we'd like to back out.  You said that:

> The top commit is wrongly pushed

so that's the commit we'd like to back out.  We could use:

```
git revert f5d394d
```

here, giving the raw hash ID (well, the abbreviated one) of the commit we want to undo.  But the *name* `master` currently points *to* `f5d394d`, so `git revert master` will also work.

Git will now take a look at commits `G` and `H`—both snapshots—to figure out what *changed* in commit `H`.  Then, Git will undo, or back out, each of these changes.  This is guaranteed to work, and produces a new snapshot that matches the old snapshot in commit `G`—which is fine; that's the snapshot we want—and then Git makes a *new* commit, which gets a new unique hash ID:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can now add on a *correct* fix, as another new commit `K`:

```
...--F--G--H--J--K   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now we can run `git push origin master` to send our commits `J` and `K` to the Git that's using our GitHub repository.  They'll add commits `J` and `K`, and then update *their* `master` to point to commit `K`.  This simply *adds on* to the commits in their repository.

(Note that they won't get our commit `I`.  We can't find it, so our Git doesn't bother to send it to them.  Even if we did send it to them—which we won't—we never ask them to set any *name* by which to find it, so they won't find it.)